# Use "where" or "inner join" on multiple column matching

Tags: mysql, inner-join

[image: Description of query]

I have tables, Table_A and Table_B with 0.2 and 2.11 millions rows respectively. I need to set the field in `Table_A.Score` as `1`, whereever I find a match of `A1=B1 and A2=B2 and A3=B3 and A4=B4`.

I am using the query 
`update Table_A, Table_B 
 set score=1 
 where A1=B1 and A2=B2 and A3=B3 and A4=B4;`

However, this query is taking too long (3 days), as per my understanding. And I can imagine so too; because for every update of Table_A row (0.2 million of those), MySQL has to check for 4 combinations across every row of Table_B (2.11 million rows).

However, I was wondering if there was something I was not doing right. Lack of primary keys index can certainly be one, for every unique combination of `p,q,r,s`.

I also tried the query with inner join:

`update Table_A 
 inner join Table_B 
 on A1=B1 and A2=B2 and A3=B3 and A4=B4
 set Score =1`

which is still running. I just wanted to get a sense of MySQL's working in this scenario, especially if `where` and `inner join` have performance issues for large tables. Though, I don't think it should make a significant difference.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Edit: `Table_A (id int(1), A1 varchar, A2 varchar, A3 varchar, A4 varchar, score int(1))`

`Table_B (B1 varchar, B2 varchar, B3 varchar, B4 varchar)`

`Explain` output is:

`| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table A | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  230309 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table B | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2035913 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------+---------------+------+--`

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the two tables? Can you show us the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT A.* FROM A JOIN B ON A1=B1 AND A2=B2 AND A3 = B3 AND A4=B4`?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table at all?

Comment: @GrandmasterB : Only Table_A has a primary index.

Comment: @Benny there's your problem :-)

Comment: @GrandmasterB: Yes, I know, its a bad database design :) Gotta work with it though, for time being. .

Comment: @Benny I don't think there's anything wrong with the tables... it just needs some indexes.  Add indexes like Gordon suggests below and I bet you'll see a 100x speedup at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is correct.  You want an index on `Table_B(B1, B2, B3, B4)`.

Note that if you are doing a large'ish number of updates, then the overhead for locking and logging can be significant.

How long does the corresponding `SELECT` take:

```
select *
from Table_A inner join
     Table_B 
     on A1 = B1 and A2 = B2 and A3 = B3 and A4 = B4;
```

Comment: That did the trick. The speed-up achieved was incredible! The previous query without the indexes was running for 3.5 days. Now, the same query with indexing completed in 2:40 minutes! Its amazing. I mean, I always "knew" that indexing makes the query run faster, however this is the first time, I am "seeing" how it makes it faster. I learnt something new :) and MySQL is amazing!